# Jquery form submit blank values

Tags: jquery, html, grails, gsp

I ran into some trouble when using the Jquery modal dialog box. What I'm trying to do here is to get the form submitted to the controller, however its submitting blank values after i click ok. This is the Jquery Codes:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var username = $( "#username" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( username ).add( email ).add( password ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    $( "#create1" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

          bValid = bValid && checkLength( username, "username", 3, 16 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( username, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
          // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

          if ( bValid ) {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              $('#createUser').submit();

          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    $( "#create" ).button().click(function() {
        $( "#create1" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });
  </script>
```

This is the html codes:

```
    <div id="create1" title="Create new user">
              <form id="createUser" method="get" name="createUser">
              <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>


        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
      </form>
    </div>
```

So, what went wrong here. I've been looking out for naming issues but it isn't helping. Is there anyone who knows how to fix this? Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong here, Look like you clear all input value before you submit the form.

```
if ( bValid ) {
  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
  $('#createUser').submit();
}
```

and

```
close: function() {
  allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
}
```

Comment: ohhhhh. I removed the line and got it fix. Any idea what is the remove class about??

Comment: do you remove $( this ).dialog( "close" ); I think it's ok if your page will be reload after submit. but if you remove allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" ); you will show dialog with old value and last error when user intent to close and reopen dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This may help ,try to Get the Values from the html page such as `$( "#username" ).val();`

Comment: I don't get it, where do you place that at?

Comment: `var username = $( "#username" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),` What is this doing?

Comment: To initialize the input fields in the jquery modal dialog box. And i can't seem to figure out where to get the values of this input boxes